# What IPC standard guides on the design of through hole PCB pads?

Tags: pcb-design, through-hole, ipc

Through hole PCB pads need an annular ring and will have other details like the solder mask clearance. For pad that shall be used to solder component leads, I believe that there is some IPC guidance on the annular ring size and hole size for given component lead diameter. Does anyone know what IPC standard this is?

Answer (score 3):

I think  both [IPC-2222](https://www.ipc.org/TOC/IPC-2222A.pdf) and [IPC-2221](https://www.ipc.org/TOC/IPC-2221A.pdf)

Comment: Could you guide me to specific section in case you are aware of it? I shall search for these on google.

Comment: I linked the tables of content on the official website.